# How to change kernel security level?

Tags: mac, security, kernel

My Mac had a kernel security level of 0. Then, I changed the kernel security level to 1.

Here's how I changed it to 1: `sysctl kern.securelevel=1`

I'd like to change it back to 0 because my hosts file has a system immutable flag on it.

This is the code for that- `sudo chflags schg /etc/hosts`

I'd like to take away the system immutable flag, and that starts with changing the secure level back to 0.

I've tried to boot into single user mode. I shut down my computer and then held down cmd+S when I rebooted. It shows a black screen and white code scrolling across the screen and then went into the regular user selection field. Then, I put in my password to log in and it showed more white code scrolling across the screen and then it logged me in and everything appears normal.

This is related to this

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282339/protect-hosts-file

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390746/how-to-change-kernel-security-level

Comment: One way to do what you want to achieve would be to set a sticky bit on the folder where the file is hosted, i.e. /etc in your case.

Comment: What does that mean?